# Semantics of identifier line in Python

Tags: python-2.7, semantics, identifier

What is the semantics of a Python 2.7 line containing ONLY identifier. I.e. simply

```
a
```

or

```
something
```

?

If you know the exact place in the Reference, I'd be very pleased.
Tnx.

Comment: The short answer is it doesn't do anything (except possibly cause a `NameError` if e.g. `a` isn't defined).

Comment: @jonrsharpe But I didn't know it and it was exactly what I needed. I saw the code
`try:
   ip1_i_im1
  except NameError:
   ip1_i_im1 = "None"`
for the first time in my life.

Comment: That seems like a hack to me - much easier to assign `ip1_1_im1 = "None"` *before* whatever could fail to assign it.

Comment: Well, probably. But the author of the script I'm getting through decided it's more convenient method to find out if the variable was created. Anyway, through THIS METHOD he pushed me to finding something new about Python.

Answer (score 3):

An identifier by itself is a valid [expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#atoms). An expression by itself on a line is a valid [statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements).

The full semantic chain is a little more involved. In order to have nice operator precedence, we classify things like "a and b" as technically both an `and_test` and an `or_test`. As a result, a simple identifier technically qualifies as over a dozen grammar items

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)
expr_stmt: testlist_star_expr (augassign (yield_expr|testlist) |
                     ('=' (yield_expr|testlist_star_expr))*)
testlist_star_expr: (test|star_expr) (',' (test|star_expr))* [',']
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
or_test: and_test ('or' and_test)*
and_test: not_test ('and' not_test)*
not_test: 'not' not_test | comparison
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
expr: xor_expr ('|' xor_expr)*
xor_expr: and_expr ('^' and_expr)*
and_expr: shift_expr ('&' shift_expr)*
shift_expr: arith_expr (('<<'|'>>') arith_expr)*
arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
term: factor (('*'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
power: atom trailer* ['**' factor]
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

a `stmt` can be composed of a single `simple_stmt`, which can be composed of a simgle `small_stmt`, which can be composed of a single `expr_stmt`, and so on, down through `testlist_star_expr`, `test`, `or_test`, `and_test`, `not_test`, `comparison`, `expr`, `xor_expr`, `and_expr`, `shift_expr`, `arith_expr`, `term`, `factor`, `power`, `atom`, and finally `NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple expression statement: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html

Comment: Almost there! More precisely, what I was searching for was section 5.2.1. Identifiers (Names) and the line "When the name is bound to an object, evaluation of the atom yields that object. When a name is not bound, an attempt to evaluate it raises a NameError exception."